# How to serve multiple domains with a single ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dns, multi-tenant

How to implement a mechanism (within a single ASP.NET MVC application) to ensure that:

- if request comes on mydomain (user visits mydomain.com) -> handle using certain set of controllers
- if request comes on otherdomain (user visits otherdomain.com) -> handle using different set of controllers

(the domains are aliased to the same web hosting)

What extension points within ASP.NET MVC should I use to ensure that the described mechanism works?

Comment: If you have 2 different domains and two sets of controllers, why would you want to put everything in one application?

Comment: currently, the reason is because the whole thing is hosted on a shared hosting - if I had my own dedicated server, I would put this into two applications of course :) The other sites should be also created and maintained almost automatically.

Comment: what did you end up doing? i hope you managed to go for two applications. sounds much cheaper in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could implement a `IRouteConstraint` descendant that analyzes the current `HttpContext` and matches (or does not match) a route depending on the domain requested. Then have two different default routes in your *Global.asax* file, each with different constraints.

I would still prefer two applications, but it's your choice of course.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I have been looking for. I'd prefer two apps as well, but this will not be my decision to take :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set up 2 web applications that share common code in a DLL? Each web app would be a standard MVC application.

Comment: there is no common code to share between the applications - the point is to serve multiple applications within a single ASP.NET MVC "container" deployed on a shared web hosting